# Writing windows service in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, .net-core

My question is How can I write the windows service in .net core which we used to write in prior .net versions ?

Lots of links/articles explain how to host your .net core application as windows service. So this is the only way I can create windows service ?

If yes, can anyone please provide the links/example of it

Thanks !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a default way of doing this.  You can however let your core application inherit from [ServiceBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase(v=vs.110).aspx) and implement the necessary overrides.  We do this in our application (note that we target the full framework, not core).  The original idea for this came from the following articles:

- [How to Run DNX Applications in a Windows Service](http://taskmatics.com/blog/run-dnx-applications-windows-service/)
- [How to Host ASP.NET in a Windows Service](https://taskmatics.com/blog/host-asp-net-in-a-windows-service/)
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755774/hosting-asp-net5-web-application-in-windows-service) also references the same articles.

Note that these articles still reference [DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) (from the .NET Core beta days) - these days your core app will compile to an exe, so you can adjust their examples to cater for that.

Comment: I read that there another class Microsoft's `WebHostService` class, which class is appropriate to use `ServiceBase` or  `WebHostService` class ?

Comment: Seems that WebHostService is the new way of doing it (I see from the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.windowsservices.webhostservice) that it does inherit from ServiceBase).  According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346383/hosting-asp-net-core-as-windows-service) question, it was added in RC2.  There is also a nice example on how to use it.  Also look at [this](http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-host-your-aspnet-core-in-a-windows-service/) article.

Answer (score 8):

*This is another simple way to build windows service in .net Core (console app)*

## [DotNetCore.WindowsService](https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService)

Simple library that allows one to host dot net core application as windows services.

### Installation

Using nuget:
**Install-Package PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService**

### Usage

1. Create .NETCore console app.
2. Create your first service, something like this:

   ```
   public class ExampleService : IMicroService
   {
       public void Start()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("I started");
       }

       public void Stop()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("I stopped");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Api for services:

   ```
   ServiceRunner<ExampleService>.Run(config =>
   {
       var name = config.GetDefaultName();
       config.Service(serviceConfig =>
       {
           serviceConfig.ServiceFactory((extraArguments) =>
       {
           return new ExampleService();
       });
       serviceConfig.OnStart((service, extraArguments) =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Service {0} started", name);
           service.Start();
       });

       serviceConfig.OnStop(service =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Service {0} stopped", name);
           service.Stop();
       });

       serviceConfig.OnError(e =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Service {0} errored with exception : {1}", name, e.Message);});
       });
   });
   ```
4. Run the service without arguments and it runs like console app.
5. Run the service with **action:install** and it will install the service.
6. Run the service with **action:uninstall** and it will uninstall the service.
7. Run the service with **action:start** and it will start the service.
8. Run the service with **action:stop** and it will stop the service.

Comment: tested in .net core 2.0

Comment: May I have the project that you have used to test with .net core 2.0?

Comment: @HaseebJadoon Sure, I'll put it on the GitHub and post the link for you (probably here, in next comment)  ;)

Comment: [Sample Service](https://github.com/SorenZ/DotNetConsoleService) based on main repository sample. I hope it would be helpful ;)

Comment: Do you have a running service for Nano Server as well? This project refers DotNet Framework dlls thus it should not work there according to my knowledge. What's your say on it?

Comment: @HaseebJadoon nope, It's running on _Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter_, as I know the target framework is `.net Core` and should run independently of `Full .net Framework` but didn't test on any other OSs.

Comment: Runs with Nano Server as well

Answer (score 2):

[This is](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service) one way of building windows services using .net core.

> It is built using P/Invoke calls into native windows assemblies.

Example of writing windows service (taken from github project's page):

```
using DasMulli.Win32.ServiceUtils;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myService = new MyService();
        var serviceHost = new Win32ServiceHost(myService);
        serviceHost.Run();
    }
}

class MyService : IWin32Service
{
    public string ServiceName => "Test Service";

    public void Start(string[] startupArguments, ServiceStoppedCallback serviceStoppedCallback)
    {
        // Start coolness and return
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // shut it down again
    }
}
```

It is [not perfect](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service#limitations) but IMHO it is pretty nice.

Comment: This looks fantastic

Comment: How can i run Controller from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc?